# How well known is the formula of carbonic acid?

Tags: molecules

My chemistry teacher in high school didn't know the formula for carbonic acid, which struck me as something someone with a degree in chemistry (as they allegedly do) should know instantly, or at least after some time thinking. However, to give them the benefit of the doubt - is carbonic acid a relativly common chemical, or alternatively is there a well known way to derive its formula from the name (like how you can work out the formula for a molecule called something somethingelseide for instance)? Should someone with a degree in chemistry know it off the top of their head?

Comment: There are rules for naming acids, one of which is that any anion ending in -ate changes to an -ic when it becomes an acid. So for example, carbonic acid would have the anion as carbonate. Carbonate should be relatively well known as CO3, and since it has a 2- charge there must be 2 hydrogens to make it neutral, thus making the formula H2CO3.

Comment: Just a side note - not all chemistry teachers have chemistry degrees.

Comment: @Helios This teacher has told us that she has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Carbonic acid has the formula $\ce{H2CO3}$ - you can't always immediately derive the formula from the (trivial) name - you have to learn it. And - yes - carbonic acid is a relatively common chemical : you can find it in all types of fizzy drinks (fanta, cola,sprite,....)

However, you can derive the formula from the other name (systematic) of carbonic acid, dihydrogen carbonate =  $\ce{H2CO3}$.

Comment: Actually, you can indeed derive the formula from the name. See my comment to the the original post.

Comment: @user2612743, that's correct:) - in the case of carbonic acid that is a good solution

Answer (score 1):

If there is open water and air, there is carbonic acid; carbonated beveradges including beer and champagne; and you are filled with it from aerobic respiration.  pH vs. pKa determines ionization.  (The leading lowercase "p" means "negative logarithm of.")

Naming simple acids:  The root is the element- bor(on), car(bon), nitr(ogen), sulfur, chlor(ine) phosphor(us).  Suffix shows oxidation state, ous/ite (low) and ic/ate high.  Prefix intensifies suffix.

Hydrochloric, Cl(-1) ("hydro" in context means "no oxygen") chlorides 
Hypochlorous, Cl(+1) hypochlorites 
chlorous, Cl(+3) chlorites 
chloric, Cl(+3) chlorates 
perchloric, Cl(+5) perchlorates

Simple names become not simple when complex structures form from concatination (peroxysulfuric acid,polyphosphoric acid), element substitution (thiosulfuric acid), substituents (methanesulfonic acid, chlorosulfonic acid), and general diddling around (adenosine triphosphate).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxyanion